# Passing a StorageFile to OnNavigatedTo in a C# WinRT app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, storagefile

In my C# WinRT app, I would like to pass a StorageFile to a new navigation page inside a frame so that the page can open the document and put the file's contents into a RichEditBox. I've tried to add an optional parameter to OnNavigatedTo with a StorageFile, but it causes the app to crash.

I tried to make it so that I can navigate to the page like this from another page that contains a frame:

```
RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Editor), file);
```

And launch the framed page like so:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e, Windows.Storage.StorageFile file)
        {
            if (file)
            {
                try
                {
                    EditorBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file));
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

But doing this, I get the following errors:

- `'TestApp.Page3.OnNavigatedTo(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs, Windows.Storage.StorageFile)' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'TestApp.Page3'`
- `'TestApp.Page3.OnNavigatedTo(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs, Windows.Storage.StorageFile)': no suitable method found to override`

Is there any way to do something similar to what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only override existing methods. You can't override what doesn't exist - you'd create something new instead. However Windows wouldn't call a method it doesn't know. So stick with what Windows has to offer:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var file = e.Parameter as Windows.Storage.StorageFile;
    if (file!=null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```